# What is "Modern Perl"?

Tags: perl

I have been hearing a lot about this "Modern Perl." What is it?

One of the things I heard was the new open syntax:

```
open my $FH, '<', $filename
```

and not

```
open FH, "<$filename";
```

What else is in Modern Perl?

Comment: [To tackle your example head on, I argue that the procedural IO isn't modern Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=763565) -- so already we see a difference in this term that can very easily be likened to "Web 2.0".

Comment: Modern Perl == http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/   </joke>

Comment: I think a more controversial and interesting question would be, *Can I write modern OO perl without the use of `Moose`?*

Comment: @whaley: Did they rewrite Ruby under Parrot?

Comment: Shouldn't this be Community-Wiki?

Comment: @Sinan - I was about to disagree with you when i realized that this same user also brougght us this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129801/how-is-modern-c-written

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To add some specifics to deinst's overview, Modern Perl:

- uses Perl 5.10's [new features](http://dev.perl.org/perl5/news/2007/perl-5.10.0.html), like [switch statements](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-statements) (`given` / `when`) and [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html)
- follows good Perl programming practices, like `use strict` and `use warnings`
- may use the [Modern::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~chromatic/Modern-Perl-1.03/lib/Modern/Perl.pm) CPAN module to streamline all of this
- uses [Moose](https://moose.iinteractive.com/en/) for writing high-level OO code

Comment: Also: avoiding global variables, preferring lexical scoped ones and accessors, writing modular and reusable code, using CPAN, tests, tests and more tests!

Comment: The `switch` you linked to is not a Perl 5.10 feature. It's a, now deprecated, core module. You might want be thinking of [`given`/`when`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-statements)

Comment: Don't forget using Perl::Critic and PerlTidy to help maintain consistent style.  Plus using some sort of version control software (git, subversion, etc).

Comment: I would avoid `given` / `when` while writing modern Perl code.

Answer (score 13):

To quote the [source](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/index.html)

> Modern Perl programming, circa 2010, relies on the collected wisdom of the entire Perl 
>   ecosystem. It's time to write elegant, reliable, maintainable, well-tested, and predictable 
>   code.

See also, [the book](http://github.com/chromatic/modern_perl_book).  And this quote from the book

> Modern Perl is a loose description of how experienced and effective Perl 5 programers work. They use language idioms. They take advantage of the CPAN. They're recognizably Perlish, and they show good taste and craftsmanship and a full understanding of Perl.

Answer (score 2):

Modern Perl isn't a proper noun; it's just something people might say to refer to Perl code that uses features only available in the last X years, where X will vary from person to person.

For information about various changes to Perl, see the perldelta files, for instance at http://perldoc.perl.org/index-history.html.

Comment: (Yes, the book title and module name are proper nouns, but that's clearly not what was meant in the question.)

Comment: It just occurred to me to wonder if Modern Perl meant to imply a contrast to post-modern perl.

Comment: since "modern perl" is always relative to now, there can't be a post-modern perl :)

Comment: I think the usage of modern in post-modern is in reference to an architectural style of the 50's that's after functionalism and minimalism. So in fact, Modern Perl could be newer that post-modern perl, as well as modern.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be specific to your question related to opening a file handle in modern Perl: You should use the three-argument form, instead two-argument form!

Use the three-argument form of `open` to specify I/O layers (also called "disciplines") to apply to the handle. It affects how read-write is processed (see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html  for more details). For example:

```
open(my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", "filename")
|| die "can't open UTF-8 encoded filename: $!";
```